# Parse a file to pull out 2 sets of information

Tags: parsing, unix, awk

I have a log file that keeps a record of user inputs.  Each line in the log is unique and I need to pull out 2 specific items - a userId and a URL.  I can't just use `awk < file '{print$1, print$6}'` because the items are not always in the same position in each line.

Example text:

```
userId='1' managed:no address:123street phone:1234567890 http:/someurl.com
newuser:yes userId='2' managed:yes address:123street  http:/someurl.com
userId='3' address:123 street phone:1234567890 http:/someurl.com
userId='4' managed:no address:123street phone:1234567890 http:/someurl.com
```

I need to parse the userId and URL address to a file, but these are not always in the same position in each line. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;$i!~/userId/;i++); print $i, $NF}' file
userId='1' http:/someurl.com
userId='2' http:/someurl.com
userId='3' http:/someurl.com
userId='4' http:/someurl.com
```

Comment: Thank you. I expect my super powers will kick in at any second.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) code :

```
gawk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ "^userId=") id=gensub(/userId=\047([0-9]+)\047/, "\\1", "", $i)
        else if ($i ~ "^http") url=$i
        print "In line "NR", the id is "id" and the url is "url
}' file.txt
```

**Sample input :**

```
userId='1' managed:no address:123street phone:1234567890 http:/someurl1.com
newuser:yes userId='2' managed:yes address:123street  http:/someurl2.com
userId='3' address:123 street phone:1234567890 http:/someurl3.com
userId='4' managed:no address:123street phone:1234567890 http:/someurl4.com
```

**Sample output :**

```
In line 1, the id is 1 and the url is http:/someurl1.com
In line 2, the id is 2 and the url is http:/someurl2.com
In line 3, the id is 3 and the url is http:/someurl3.com
In line 4, the id is 4 and the url is http:/someurl4.com
```

**This solution have the advantage to have id or http items to be anywhere you'd want in lines.**

Comment: Updated to display integers without single quotes using gawk and capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for(c=1;c<NF;c++){if(match($c,/userId/)){print $c,$NF; break}}}' your.file
```

Output:

```
userId='1' http:/someurl.com
userId='2' http:/someurl.com
userId='3' http:/someurl.com
userId='4' http:/someurl.com
```

Comment: I'm missing something here.  This command doesn't return any lines and how do you get the 'http' results? Thanks.

Comment: I've tested it with you posted data. The output that I've posted is from my test-run. The http url is always the last column in your input, that's why `$NF` (NF is the field per line count in awk)